# preg_replace and an array not working

Tags: php, arrays, preg-replace

This doesn't work.  I expect it to replace each coinsurance of the array values with ralph.  Instead, I get the unchanged value of $data back.  Any insight as to why?

```
$data="there is a dog in the car out back";

$bill= explode(' ',$data);

$bob[0]="dog";
$bob[1]="car";
$bob[2]="back";

$qq = preg_replace("|($bob)|Ui", "ralph" , htmlspecialchars($data));

echo $qq;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you interpolate an array like `$bob` in string context `"$bob"` then it just becomes `"Array"`.

At the very least you would need to `implode` it again as alternatives list:

```
$regex_bob = implode("|", $bob);   // you should also apply preg_quote()
# $regex_bob = "dog|car|back|...";
```

And then use a more sensible regex delimiter (as `|` is used for the alternatives):

```
$qq = preg_replace("~($regex_bob)~Ui", "ralph" , htmlspecialchars($data));
```

Comment: thank you, all responses have been helpful.  I appreciate your time.  CC

Answer (score 1):

Just try this:

```
echo "|($bob)|Ui";
```

...and you will see what the problem is. If you just place an array into a string, it results in the string `Array` being added to the string - so the actual regex you are executing is:

```
"|(Array)|Ui"
```

You need to explicitly tell PHP *how* to convert the array to a string - in this case, I suggest you use `implode()`:

```
$expr = "/(".implode('|',$bob).")/Ui";
$qq = preg_replace($expr, "ralph" , htmlspecialchars($data));
// Should return "there is a ralph in the ralph out ralph"
```

Note that I have also changed the delimiter to `/` - this is because you need to use `|` literally in the regex, so it is best to pick another delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

Use it this way:

```
$data="there is a dog in the car out back";

$bill= explode(' ',$data);

$bob[0]="/dog/ui";
$bob[1]="/car/ui";
$bob[2]="/back/ui";

echo preg_replace($bob, "ralph", $data);
```

You have to pass a list of regular expressions, which you want to replace with a string or a list of replacements. More information: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php